# How to box and individually colour this text?

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to HTML and CSS, in fact this is the first thing I've tried to do with it.

I'm trying to make a little key.

I'd like the key to be boxed (around the width of the text, not the page width) and the names to be coloured in red and blue. Excuse this, I don't know how best else to represent it.

```
             ---------------------
             |        Key:       |
             |                   |
             | Matt (in Blue)    |
             | Kerry (in Red)    |
             ---------------------
```

Key is centred to the box. There is a single space between the Key and Matt. And no space, but a new line inbetween Matt and Kerry.

I've had trouble doing this without double < /br>. If I make the names each a < p> then there is a space inbetween them. Either way I am unsure how I can individually colour these names, as far as I have learnt my red and blue css class (.r and .b) have to be used within a tag, but I can only use one class on a single < h1> or < p>, right?

Here is what I have in my CSS

```
    .b {
            color: blue;}
    .r {
            color: red;}
    .key { 
            border-style: groove;}
```

and my HTML

```
  <p class="key">Key:</p>
  <p class="b">Matt</p>
  <p class="r">Kerry</p>
```

That creates a box around the words key only, and whilst it correctly colors, there is a space between those names I don't want.

Solution:

```
    .b {
            color: blue;
            }
    .r {
            color: red;}
    .key { 
            border-style: groove;
            width:75px;}
    .centre {
            text-align:center;
```

and for HTML

```
<p class="key centre">Key:<br><br>
<span class="b">Matt <br> </span>
<span class="r">Kerry <br> </span>
Both <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
<div class="key">
  <p>Key:</p>
  <p class="b">Matt</p>
  <p class="r">Kerry</p>
</div>
```

spacing between the words can be completed with css margin.

```
.b{
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `<p>`'s with something, probably a `<div>`:

```
<div class="key">
    <p>Key:</p>
    <p class="b">Matt</p>
    <p class="r">Kerry</p>
</div>
```

To control the width of the box, you can use the `width` css property:

```
.key {
    width:300px;
}
```

(There are other ways to have the width of the box not be the whole width, for instance the box will auto fit the content if you float it or absolutely position it.)

To center the 'key' text, you will probably want to use `text-align:center`, maybe using a class or maybe using the [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) pseudo class:

```
.center {
    text-align:center;
}

.key p:first-of-type {
    text-align:center;
}
```

You can use multiple classes on an element, just separate them with a space, e.g. `<div class="key center">`

You can also reference multiple classes in one rule set like so:

```
.r, .b {
    margin:0;
}
```

This way there will be no spacing between the red and blue text.

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful! Although I had stumbled on a solution before reading this... I don't think its very, er, elegant however.. added to the OP to show.